# What the frequency of the Garbage Collection in Java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Page 6 of the the document [Memory Management in the Java
HotSpot™ Virtual Machine](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf) contains the following paragraphs:

> Young generation collections occur relatively frequently and are
>   efficient and fast because the young generation space is usually small
>   and likely to contain a lot of objects that are no longer referenced.
>
> Objects that survive some number of young generation collections are
>   eventually promoted, or tenured, to the
>       old generation. See Figure 1. This generation is typically larger than the young generation and its occupancy
>       grows more slowly. As a result, old generation collections are infrequent, but take significantly longer to
>       complete

Could someone please define what "*frequent*" and "*infrequent*" mean in the statements above? Are we talking **microseconds, milliseconds, minutes, days**?

Comment: The answer: "It depends."  There's no hard & fast time scale.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is not possible to give a definite answer to this.  It really depends on a lot of factors, including the platform (JVM version, settings, etc), the application, and the workload.

At one extreme, it is possible for an application to never trigger a garbage collector.  It might simply sit there doing nothing, or it might perform an extremely long computation in which no objects are created after the JVM initialization and application startup.

At the other extreme it is theoretically possible for one garbage collection end and another one to start *within few nanoseconds*.  For example, this could happen if your application is in the last stages of dying from a full heap, or if it is allocating pathologically large arrays.

So:

> Are we talking microseconds, milliseconds, minutes, days?

Possibly all of the above, though the first two would definitely be troubling if you observed them in practice.

A *well behaved* application should not run the GC too often.  If your application is triggering a young space collection more than once or twice a second, then this could  lead to performance problems.  And too frequent "full" collections is worse because their impact is greater.  However, it is certainly plausible for a poorly designed / implemented application to behave like this.

---

There is also the issue that the interval between GC runs is not always meaningful.  For instance some of the HotSpot GCs actually have GC threads running concurrently with normal application threads.  If you have enough cores, enough RAM and enough memory bus bandwidth, then a constantly running concurrent GC *may* not appreciably affect application performance.

Terminology note:

- Strictly speaking a concurrent GC is one where the GC can run at the same time as the application threads.
- Strictly speaking a parallel GC is one where the GC itself uses multiple threads.
- A GC can be concurrent without being parallel, and vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

Its a relative term.  Young collections could be many times a seconds up to a few hours.  Old generations collections can be every few seconds, up to daily.  You should expect to have many more young collections than old collections in a most systems.

Its highly unlikely to be many days. If the GC occurs too often e.g. << 100 ms apart you get get a `OutOfMemoryError: GC Overhead Exceeded` as the JVM prevenets that from happening.

Comment: Indeed, if you have a service that nothing talks to, then the GC might never run.

Comment: My default, a JVM will support JMX and perform a Full GC every hour if it doesn't perform a minor collection. See `sun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval`and `sun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval` in http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/sunrmiproperties.html

Comment: Took some head scratching to work that one out because it can mean that if you reduce your minor collections, in say a trading system, you can find the rate of spurious full gc's increases. :P

Comment: Ah yes, but that behaviour is platform specific.  Besides, I was merely pointing out a *possible* scenario, and it is clearly possible to turn JMX off.

Comment: True, You can turn those options off even in HotSpot.

Comment: You can at least exchange the Full GC for an Old GC using `-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrentAndUnloadsClasses` (or `-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent`), though.

Comment: @FrankPavageau - my understanding is that those are about what happens when you explicitly call `System.gc()` ... and that is not what the OP is talking about.

Comment: @StephenC That also applies to the GCs triggered by the JMX/RMI support that Peter was talking about (in the Oracle JVM). I guess they're explicit GCs as well.

Answer (score 0):

As it is, the terms "frequent" , "infrequent" are relative. And the timings are, in fact, not fixed. It depends on the system in question. It depends on lots of things like:

- Your heap size and settings for different parts of the heap (young, old gen, perm gen)
- Your application's memory behaviour. How many objects does it create and how fast? how long those objects are referenced etc?

If your application is monster memory eater, gc would run as if its running for its life. If your application does not demand too much of memory, then gc would run at intervals decided by how full the memory is.

Answer (score 0):

TL DL: "Frequent" and "infrequent" are relative terms that depends on the memory allocation rate and the heap size. If you want a precise answer, you need to measure it yourself for your particular application.

Let's say your app has two modes, mode-1 allocates memory and does computation and mode-2 sits idle.

If mode-1 allocation is smaller than the heap available, no gc need to occur until it finishes. Maybe it used so little RAM that it could do a second round of mode-1 without collection. However, eventually you'll run out of free heap, and jvm will perform an "infrequent" collection.

However, if mode-1 allocation is a significant fraction of, or larger, than the young-generation heap, collection would happen more "frequently". During the young gen collection, allocations that survive (imagine data is needed through the entire mode-1 operation), will be promoted to old-gen, giving the young-gen more room. Young-gen allocation and collection can now continue. Eventually old-gen heap would run out, and must be collected, thus "infrequently".

So then, how frequent is frequent? It depends on the allocation rate and the heap size. If jvm is bumping into the heap limit often, it'll collect often. If there is plenty of heap (let's say 100GB), then jvm doesn't need to collect for a long long time. The down side is that when it finally does a collection, it might take a long time to free 100GB, stopping the jvm for many seconds (or minutes!). The current JVMs are smarter than that and would occasionanlly force a collection (preferably in mode-2). And with parallel collectors, it could happen all the time if necessary.

Ultimately, the frequency is task and heap dependent, as well as how various vm parameters are set. If you want a precise answer, you must measure them yourself for your particular application.

Answer (score -2):

Because spec says "relatively frequently" and infrequent (regarding Young generation), we can't estimate the frequency in absolute units like microseconds, milliseconds, minutes or days